# Setting object data in nested for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have a scope variable called jobs which is an array of objects for each department and their data.

[
    “Accounting”: {
        “foo” : “foo”,
        “bar” : bar"
    },
    “Delivery”: {
        “foo”: “foo”,
        “bar”: “bar
    }
]

The HTML5 date input requires that all dates be converted to using new Date() in javascript even though they are in the correct yyyy-mm-dd format specified. I could go through by hand and type in each date that needs to be converted, but I wanted to use a nested foreach to do so because I have a lot of dates to convert.

```
angular.forEach($scope.job, function(value, key){
    angular.forEach(value, function(innerValue, innerKey){
       if(typeof(innerValue) === "string"){
         var matches = innerValue.match(/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/);
         if(matches){
               // Need to set $scope.job.key.innerKey = new Date($scope.job.key.innerKey) here 
         }
       }
     });
  });
```

My issues is that I don’t know how to access the $scope.job object at the key and innerKey values I came to. How can I edit the current item being looped over? The documentation on using ‘this’ in a situation like this was almost impossible to find.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `[]` object notation for variable property names

```
if(matches){
   value[innerKey] = new Date(value[innerKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to make a directive wrapping the date input and put the conversion logic in the controller of that directive. This way all the looping would be implicitly done by the framework, for all instances of the custom date input directive.